# Assets not found in prod using Webpack Encore with Symfony3.4

Tags: php, symfony-3.4, webpack-encore

I developed a website based on Symfony 3.4 and using Webpack Encore to manage assets. When I deployed the last release, CSS/JS assets were not found:

[image]

When I inspected the source code of the web page, I saw that URLs are pointing to the old versions of the assets, like `/build/app.db32012d.css` while the file `manifest.json` is referencing the new versions of assets:

```
{
  "build/app.css": "/build/app.2aba4862.css"
}
```

I use [deployer](https://deployer.org) to deploy new releases. The deployment process builds assets running `yarn encore prod`.

First of all, I tried to warmup/clear the Symfony cache but still stuck.

When I browse the site in dev environement (calling `app_dev.php`) the problem disapears.

I tried to restart Apache but still stuck.

I changed the `DocumentRoot` of the VirtualHost from `/var/www/current/web` to `/var/www/foo/web` and the problem disapears until the next release.

Here is my stack:

- Apache 2.4
- php7.3.6-fpm
- OPCache enabled
- HTTP2 enabled

I expect the assets URLs to be pointing to the new versions as specified in the `manifest.json` file.

I suspect a cache issue somewhere but I can't find where.

Comment: how did you deploy your last release ? Did you run `yarn encore production` ?

Comment: Oh I forgot to explain that part: I deployed using [deployer](https://deployer.org) tool.
In the deployment process it runs `yarn encore prod`:

```php
task('build:assets', function() {
    run('yarn install');
    run('yarn encore prod');
    run('bin/console ckeditor:install');
    run('bin/console assets:install web');
})->local();
```

Comment: I think I found a solution : `service php7.3-fpm restart`.
Does it make sens ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I found the answer. Versionned assets are loaded in Twig templates using functions `encore_entry_link_tags` and `encore_entry_script_tags` ([Official doc](https://symfony.com/doc/current/frontend/encore/simple-example.html)).
These functions read from an `entrypoints.json` file that's generated by Encore to know the exact filename(s) to render.
Behind theses its just PHP.
As I'm using php-fpm, I have to restart service php-fpm when I deploy a new releases of my assets:

```sh
service php7.3-fpm restart
```

That's it!